# Markers get displayed with wrong number Flutter

Tags: loops, flutter, markers

In my app I'm using flutter_bloc and flutter_map packages.When I track a route I want to to display the tracked points order so when I receive a state with a tracked route I add a marker for each point in the route using a (forEach or normal) loop and it has an icon and and a number, so I can see the marker order. The problem is that while the markers get placed correctly on the map and the icon shows correctly, the number displayed is wrong. If I print the variable that holds the value to display in the loop it prints correctly  eg. 1 to 7, but when assigned to the marker it get a wrong value of 8.
I can't find out where that 8 comes from..

Can you see what's I doing wrong here?

This is the code in the received state:

```
if (state is TrackedRoute) {
            route.clear();
            trackedPoints.clear();
            int num = 1;
            setState(() {
              route = state.trackedRoute;
            });
//              route.forEach((element) {
            for (int i = 0; i < route.length; i++) {
              LatLng element = route[i];
              print('@@@@@  num is $num'); // TODO printed number is correct
              LatLng point = LatLng(element.latitude, element.longitude);
              Marker trackedPoint = Marker(
                point: point,
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                builder: (context) => Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  children: [
                    // TODO Prints all 8s ???!!!

                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_location),
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      iconSize: 30,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    Text(
                      num.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25),
                    ), // TODO :  Displayed number is wrong
                  ],
                ),
              );
              trackedPoints.add(trackedPoint);
              num++;
            }

//              });

          }
```

this is the console print:

```
I/flutter (24597): @@@@@  num is 2
I/flutter (24597): @@@@@  num is 3
I/flutter (24597): @@@@@  num is 4
I/flutter (24597): @@@@@  num is 5
I/flutter (24597): @@@@@  num is 6
I/flutter (24597): @@@@@  num is 7
```

and this is the resulting displayed rout with markers displaying a number 8:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `builder` method of the `Marker` is only called when the `MarkerLayer` is drawn on the screen. Therefore your `num` variable will have reached its maximum before the builder method is called, hence all markers will get the same `num`.

I don't think there is a good way to achieve what you want with the current `flutter_map` package. The `MarkerLayer` only calls the builder with a context, so you need some other means to achieve this. The problem is that the Marker builder has no way to access the associated Marker data.

Perhaps [the solution is in this Github issue comment](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/768#issuecomment-721237675). However this solution rebuilds the complete map when the markers change. Otherwise it might be best to open an issue on the `flutter_map` Github repository yourself.

Comment: indeed. Looks like I'll have to make a custom widget as I didi for other markers. Cheers.

Comment: If you have a solution to your question, please add it as an answer yourself (or edit mine), so others who run into the same issue can benefit.

Comment: Sure .. as soon as I have a code to upload as an answer I certainly will dear